# How to define multiple TypeScript Interfaces that return the same type structure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, interface

```
export interface UserFailureResponse {
    statusCode: number
    statusMessage: string
}

export interface UserCreateResponse {
    statusCode: number
    statusMessage: string
}

export interface AuthCheckResponse {
    statusCode: number
    statusMessage: string
}
```

Here I have created three different Response interfaces that are the same.

I am planning to create a generic interface like 'Response'. But is this the right convention with scalability and adaptability in mind?
Would like to hear from the TS community as I am new to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `extends`

```
export interface BaseResponse {
    statusCode: number
    statusMessage: string
}
export interface UserFailureResponse extends BaseResponse {    }

export interface UserCreateResponse  extends BaseResponse{     }

export interface AuthCheckResponse extends BaseResponse{  }
```